# Testing Vue.js components with Karma,jasmin and webpack

Tags: webpack, jasmine, vue.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Please see below my code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import UserTile from "../src/components/user-tile.vue";
const DataBus = require('../src/dataBus');

describe('user Tile', () => {
const getComponent = (userData) =>{
  let vm = new Vue({
    template: '<div><user-tile ref="component" :userData="userData"></user-tile></div>',
    components: {
      UserTile,
    },
    data:{
      userData
    }
  })
  return vm;
}

  it('does something', () => {
    const vm = getComponent(DataBus.pod.members[0]).$mount();
    const component= vm.$refs.component;
    console.info(component);
    expect(component.name).toBe('user-tile');
  });
});
```

I'm trying to do a really basic test and get it to validate the name of the component, set in user tile matches what is defined:

```
 export default{
name: 'user-tile'
}
```

but it always fails with:
FAILED TESTS:

```
   user Tile
    × does something
      Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 7 0.0.0)
    Expected undefined to be 'user-tile'.
        at Object.eval (eval at 492 (test/individual-user-tile-test.js:154:1), <anonymous>:33:28)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `name` property doesn't exist on component directly - it's on `$options` object, so this should work:

```
it('does something', () => {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    const vm = getComponent(DataBus.pod.members[0]).$mount(el);
    const component= vm.$refs.component;
    expect(component.$options.name).toEqual('user-tile');
});
```

Comment: This gave me the right idea but the correct answer is actually component.$options._tagName. Thank you though!

Comment: `component.$options.name` should work without any issue - tested on my machine.But anyhow, glad you got it working ;)